# Join from 3 tables

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to join 3 tables in a view; here is the situation:

I have a table `PROJECTS` that contains information of projects. table structure (`id` primary key, `project_id`.

I have another table `PROJECT_DESIGN` that lists the images used in projects. table structure ( `id`, `project_id`, `image_1`, `image_2` ).

I have another table `PROJECT_MEMBERS` that lists the members involved in projects. table structure ( `id`, `project_id`, `member_name` ).

I have 4 related rows in `PROJECT_DESIGN` with `project_id=11`.
I have 2 related rows in `PROJECT_MEMBERS` with `project_id=11`.

I want to display the data in following manner, only 4 rows like

```
id  project_title   image_1     image_2     member_name
11  test_1232321    118.png     s118.png    member_1
11  test_1232321    13.png           8.png      member_2
11  test_1232321    18.png           78.png     member_1
11  test_1232321    908.png     18.png          member_2
```

I am using following query :

```
SELECT pm.id, pm.project_title, dm.image_1, dm.image_2,tm.name
FROM PROJECTS AS pm
INNER JOIN PROJECT_DESIGN AS dm ON pm.id = dm.project_id
inner join PROJECT_MEMBERS as tm on pm.id = tm.project_id 
AND pm.id = 11
```

it gives me following result: 4 * 2

```
11  test_1232321    118.png     s118.png    member_1
11  test_1232321    13.png           8.png      member_2
11  test_1232321    18.png           78.png     member_1
11  test_1232321    908.png     18.png          member_2
11  test_1232321    118.png     s118.png    member_1
11  test_1232321    13.png           8.png      member_2
11  test_1232321    18.png           78.png     member_1
11  test_1232321    908.png     18.png          member_2
```

Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT pm.id, pm.project_title, dm.core_design, dm.overlay_design, dm.orientation, tm.name, tm.designation, tm.image
FROM PROJECTS AS pm
INNER JOIN PROJECT_DESIGN AS dm ON pm.id = dm.project_id
inner join PROJECT_MEMBERS as tm on pm.id = tm.project_id 
WHERE pm.id = 11
GROUP BY pm.id
```

the and makes it part of the join condition.

added a group by

try select distinct

```
SELECT DISTINCT pm.id, pm.project_title, dm.core_design, dm.overlay_design, dm.orientation, tm.name, tm.designation, tm.image
FROM PROJECTS AS pm
INNER JOIN PROJECT_DESIGN AS dm ON pm.id = dm.project_id
inner join PROJECT_MEMBERS as tm on pm.id = tm.project_id 
WHERE pm.id = 11
GROUP BY pm.id.
```

Comment: you shoud also group by pm.id

Comment: above query also have same problem. returns 8 rows instead of 4 rows

Comment: by adding group by it returns only 1 row, actually id 11 has 4 related rows in PROJECT_DESIGN and 2 related rows PROJECT_MEMBERs

Comment: Can you make an SQL fiddle with some test data ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fields you provided , I wrote this , even though I dont have cleare description of tables As @user1281385 says fiddle with some test data would help clarifying .

```
 CREATE TABLE Project_Design_INPUT AS 
 SELECT pm.id, pm.project_title, dm.image_1, dm.image_2
 FROM PROJECTS AS pm 
 INNER JOIN PROJECT_DESIGN AS dm ON pm.id = dm.project_id
 AND pm.id = 11


 SELECT pm.id, pm.project_title, pm.core_design, pm.overlay_design, pm.orientation, tm.name,  
 tm.designation, tm.image
 FROM Project_Design_INPUT AS pm
 inner join PROJECT_MEMBERS as tm on pm.id = tm.project_id 
 WHERE pm.id = 11
```